# Select with multiple clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

**Schema**

I have 3 tables with the following columns:

```
tblClients [ClientID, ClientName, Client Contact]
tblEvents [EventID, EventName]
tblEventBook [EventBookID, EventID, ClientID]
```

- `tblEventBook EventID` matches `tblEvents EventID`
- `tblEventBook ClientID` matches `tblClients ClientID`

I have two parameters: `@useEventID` and `@useClientID`

I would like to retrieve all rows from `tblClient` where `tblEventBook` does not equal `useEventID` and `useClientID`.

I tried to use the below, but it does not work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblClients 
WHERE tblEventBook.EventID <> @useEventID 
  AND tblEventBook.ClientID <> @useClientID
```

Sample Data:

**tblEventBook**

```
EventBookID EventID ClientID 
1           1          1 
2           2          2
3           3          1
4           4          2
```

**tblClients**

```
ClientID ClientName  ClientContact
1        TestNameA   12345
2        TestNameB   54321
```

**tblEvents**

```
EventID EventName
1       TestEventA
2       TestEventB
3       TestEventC
4       TestEventD
5       TestEventE
```

Required results

I need to get the below results when I use:

1. `@useClientID = 1, @useEventID = 1`

   It should return `ClientID 2`
2. `@useClientID = 2, @useEventID = 1`

   It should return `ClientID 1 and 2`
3. `@useClientID = 2, @useEventID = 2`

   It should return `ClientID 1`
4. `@useClientID = 5, @useEventID = 2`

   It should return `ClientID 1 and 2`

Comment: How does your question relate to C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution will exclude all tblClients with @useClientID and related tblEventBook that match @useEventID:

```
select * from tblClients c
where c.ClientID <> @useClientID
and not exists(select 1 from tblEventBook where ClientID=c.ClientID and EventID=@useEventID)
```

But from your description I also see a slightly difference possibility, where we only exclude tblClients if a related tblEventBook record exists having @useClientID and @useEventID:

```
select * from tblClients c
where not exists(
    select 1 from tblEventBook 
    where ClientID=c.ClientID 
    and EventID=@useEventID
    and ClientID=@useClientID
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I did some tests, seems working. Marked as correct for now. thanks for all others assistance as well. very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do here, but try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tblEventBook

WHERE 

EventID <> @useEventID 

AND

ClientID <> @useClientID
```

Answer (score 1):

Tough to determine exactly what you're after without some sample data and desired results, but here is my first guess from your word problem:

```
SELECT c.ClientID, c.ClientName, c.[Client Contact],
    e.EventID, e.EventName,
    eb.EventBookID
  FROM dbo.tblClients AS c
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblEventBook AS eb
  ON c.ClientID = eb.ClientID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblEvents AS e
  ON eb.EventID = e.EventID
  WHERE eb.EventID <> @useEventID
  AND eb.ClientID <> @useClientID;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your requirement correctly:

```
SELECT        *
FROM           tblClients
WHERE        (ClientID IN
                             (SELECT        ClientID
                               FROM            tblEventBook
                               WHERE        (ClientID <> @useClientID) AND (EventID <> @useEventID)))
```

Comment: This looks simple and correct to me, but when I run, it only matches the ClientID, but not the EventID.

Comment: Please post some sample data and desired results, so we can figure out what you want (which may not quite match what you think you're asking for).

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select *
from  @tblClients c
join @tblEventBook eb
on c.ClientID = eb.ClientID
where c.ClientID != @useClientID
and eb.EventBookID != @useEventID
```